# Unable to pass a function pointer to a member function of the class as an argument to another member function of the same class

Tags: c++, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

I need help... **appropriate questions have been asked in the comments.** The programs has zero compiler errors and warnings!! I have concerns with calling a member function from another member function using function pointers. (To be precise, *setMatrixto()* is trying to call *setElement()* function using function pointer)

Plus somehow the "hello there" is not being printed to the console. I was expecting it to show up as output.Maybe the *setMatrixto()* is not getting called at all!!

Header File definition

```
#ifndef MATRIXOPERATIONS_H
#define MATRIXOPERATIONS_H

class MatrixOperations;

typedef int (MatrixOperations::*INTFUNC)(int,int);
typedef void (MatrixOperations::*VOIDFUNC)(int,int,int);

class MatrixOperations
{
    public:
        MatrixOperations();
        MatrixOperations(int size);
        ~MatrixOperations();

        //diagonal matrix funtions
        void displayMatrixOf(INTFUNC f);
        void setMatrixTo(VOIDFUNC f);

        int getElement(INTFUNC from, int i, int j);
        void setElement(VOIDFUNC to,int i ,int j, int value);

        int fromDiagonalArray(int i, int j);
        void toDiagonalArray(int i, int j, int value);
    protected:

    private:
        int size;
        int* a;

};



#endif // MATRIXOPERATIONS_H
```

CPP Implementation File

```
#include "MatrixOperations.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


MatrixOperations::MatrixOperations()
{
    //ctor
    size = 3;
    a = new int[size];



}
MatrixOperations::MatrixOperations(int size)
{
    //ctor
    this->size = size;
    a = new int[size];


}


MatrixOperations::~MatrixOperations()
{
    //dtor
    delete[] a;
}




///////////////////FUCNTION POINTER SECTION///////////////////////////////////
int MatrixOperations::getElement(INTFUNC from, int i, int j)
{
    return (this->*from)(i,j);

}

void MatrixOperations::setElement(VOIDFUNC to,int i ,int j, int value)
{

    (this->*to)(i,j,value);
}




/////////////////////////////////DIAGONAL ARRAY OPERATIONS/////////////////////////////////////////////////
int MatrixOperations::fromDiagonalArray(int i, int j)
{
    if(i==j)
    {
        return a[i];
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;

    }
}
void MatrixOperations::toDiagonalArray(int i, int j, int value)
{
    a[i] = value;
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void MatrixOperations::displayMatrixOf(INTFUNC f)
{
    for(int i{0}; i < size; i++)
    {
        for(int j{0}; j < size; j++)
        {
            cout << getElement(f,i,j) << "\t"; //is this the correct way to send the function pointer?
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

}

void MatrixOperations::setMatrixTo(VOIDFUNC f)
{
    cout << "Hello there!!";                      //not getting this output.. whats wrong??
    for(int i{0}; i < size; i++)
    {


            int value {};
            cout << "Enter value diagonal element " << i << " : ";
            cin >> value;
            setElement(f,i,i,value);             //is this the correct way to send the function pointer?

    }

}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Main File

```
#include <iostream>
#include "MatrixOperations.h"

typedef MatrixOperations MATRIX;


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    MATRIX m1;

    m1.setMatrixTo(MATRIX::toDiagonalArray); //was expecting a "Hello there!" but i am not getting that output either
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT2: I added all the class definitions and main function in one single file. SURPRISINGLY!! this works . I am confused??!!!**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class MatrixOperations;

typedef void (MatrixOperations::*VOIDFUNC)(int,int,int);
typedef MatrixOperations MATRIX;

class MatrixOperations
{
    public:
        MatrixOperations();
        MatrixOperations(int size);
        ~MatrixOperations();


        //diagonal matrix funtions

        void setMatrixTo(VOIDFUNC f);
        void setElement(VOIDFUNC to,int i ,int j, int value);
        void toDiagonalArray(int i, int j, int value);
    private:
        int size;
        int* a;

};
MatrixOperations::MatrixOperations()
{    //ctor
    size = 3;
    a = new int[size];
}
MatrixOperations::MatrixOperations(int size)
{    //ctor
    this->size = size;
    a = new int[size];
}
MatrixOperations::~MatrixOperations()
{
    //dtor
    delete[] a;
}
void MatrixOperations::setElement(VOIDFUNC to,int i ,int j, int value)
{

    (this->*to)(i,j,value);
}




/////////////////////////////////DIAGONAL ARRAY OPERATIONS/////////////////////////////////////////////////
void MatrixOperations::toDiagonalArray(int i, int j, int value)
{
    a[i] = value;
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void MatrixOperations::setMatrixTo(VOIDFUNC f)
{
    cout << "Hello there!!" << endl;
    for(int i{0}; i < size; i++)
    {


            int value {};
            cout << "Enter value diagonal element " << i << " : ";
            cin >> value;
            setElement(f,i,i,value);

    }

}

int main()
{

    MATRIX m1;

    m1.setMatrixTo(MATRIX::toDiagonalArray);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not sure how your compiler is not reporting the problem.  Pass a pointer to the function  `m1.setMatrixTo(&MATRIX::toDiagonalArray);`

Comment: Add an `<< std::endl` to the output you're not seeing .. probably your program crashes before it flushes the output buffer

Comment: You are not using function pointers here.  You are using "pointers to member functions".  This is not an idle distinction; pmfs are much more complex than a simple address.

Comment: Also, please minimize your example (you don't need fromDiagonalArray for example or displayMatrix ... which means you don't need getElement, and so on).  Also, restructure it as a single file - this makes it much easier for people to copy and paste your sample.

Comment: This code should not compile due to what was already noted in the comment by RamblinRose. What compiler are you using?

Comment: @MichaelKenzel its gcc

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica added a minimized code with only the functions and operations concerned.. IN EDIT2... it works somehow

Comment: EDIT2 - I added the same code but in one single file.. THIS compiles and works perfectly. Maybe linker is having trouble or something to link all these files together??

Comment: @Parag You need to search for "How to debug small programs" by Eric Lippert and then read it.  As a rule of thumb, it's never the linker (or compiler), it's always the programmer.  You need to find what the difference is between your one-file example, and the full program.  (For example: if you remove extraneous functions from the multi-file example, does the problem go away?)  A question asking "why does this minimal three-file program not work, but this one-file program does" would be a good question here.  Alternatively, learn to step through your failing code with a debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the code in both cases. Its just my debugger was not running in admin mode. I got error code 740. So I launched my IDE in admin mode and voila it worked.